# External Hard Drive doesn't show up in "my computer" but does in "device manager"

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

IMAGE: [image]

I uninstalled Acronis true image home 2012 from my computer and my HDD (USB 2.0) doesn't show up in My Computer, but does in "device manager". First it showed "Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)" but I fix this with http:// forum.acronis.com/forum/25509#comment-83865 tutorial.

In Disk Management section don't show my HDD too.

IMAGE: [image: s]

But others programs like "MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition 7.1" shows my HDD.

IMAGE: [image: s]

Sorry for English and thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Acronis is world famous for not uninstalling completely and leaving filter drivers installed and loading on startup. I would seek help on the Acronis forum.

Comment: Does the drive actually contain any data?  It looks like the Disk Manager isn't recognizing the drive as being partitioned or formatted.  If there's no data on the drive, or the data is disposable or easily replaceable, you may want to try re-partitioning and re-formatting the drive via the Disk Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the lower half of the Disk Manager display: it is showing *two* disks, the second un-partitioned and unformatted.

Right click on this to create a partition and then format it. This process will also allow a drive letter to be assigned and then it will appear in Explorer etc.

Comment: But in other computers this HDD is working perfectly. And it has content (~1% left free).

Comment: (Rolled back edit: mixed up using the partition wizard with right click to get to it by implying you right click in the wizard.)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the drive that is not showing up then click change drive letter. change it to a unused drive letter then click ok. click apply changes. Now the drive should show up in windows explorer