# Why doesn't My Computer show my external SATA Hard Drive, when it's detected by Device Manager + Disk Management?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata

Please see red arrows below. Device Manager + Disk Management are detecting my SATA HD (Hard Drive).

[image]

But why does My Computer fail to showcase my SATA HD?

[image]

I perused [External Hard Drive doesn't show up in "my computer" but does in "device manager"](https://superuser.com/q/395188), [Why does my external hard drive not stop spinning when I put my computer to sleep?](https://superuser.com/q/1470871).

##### AfterWord

The issue is that I mixed up the Volume's Label with the "drive letter". I thought that labelling this HD [under "Format Volume"](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/windows-10/how-to-format-hard-drive-in-windows-10.html)

[image]

sufficed. I didn't know that I needed to complete another separate step —   ["Assign the following drive letter."](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/bios-detect-hard-drive-but-windows-does-not-7201.html)

[image]

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas why not put it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @YisroelTech .. I guess the points aren't all that important to me but helping people is.  I forget that my comments aren't as easy to search for future people as the posted answer.

Comment: Indeed, and for AI to train on you... to better help people asking it... 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have a drive letter associated with it.

1. Right click in disk management.
2. "Change Drive Letters and Paths".
3. Add a drive letter.

Why didn't you get one to begin with? Don't know but it happens to me occasionally. Also.. kinda stupid we are still dealing with CPM based drive letters today but it is what it is. Good luck.

Comment: "Why didn't you get one to begin with?" I edited my post. Does my AfterWord answer your question? Many thanks for assisting me!